# entity framework validation context - null exception in null test

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on PC configurator application and I have a problem with validating. Point of app is to check if socket on motherboard is the same as socket of CPU etc.

I made code first database using scaffolding in Visual Studio 2013.

```
public class Configuration : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int ConfigurationID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DisplayName("Configuration name")]
    public string ConfigName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("mb_id")]
    public MotherBoard MotherBoard { get; set; }

    [Column("mb_id", TypeName = "int")]
    public Nullable<int> mb_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("cpu_id")]
    public CPU CPU { get; set; }

    [Column("cpu_id", TypeName = "int")]
    public Nullable<int> cpu_id { get; set; }
}
```

This is part of configuration model that I am using (rest of it looks pretty similar - just other components)

I just scaffolded this model into controller.

This is start of validation and it seems like problem is somewhere here (at least VS says so).

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (MotherBoard == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("Motherboard"); }
    if (CPU == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("CPU"); }
    if (GPU == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("GPU"); }
    if (HDD == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("HDD"); }
    if (RAM == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("RAM"); }
    if (Power == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("Power"); }
    if (Case == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("Case"); }

    if (MotherBoard.CPU.ToUpper().Trim() != CPU.Socket.ToUpper().Trim())
    {
            yield return new ValidationResult("CPU socket does not match.", new[] { "cpu_id" });
    }
}
```

When I create PC configuration without validation, it goes normally into database. But when I try this validation it says that CPU (in null test) is null and throws null exception.
[Screenshot from VS.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50441081/Untitled3.png)

It never throws it on Motherboard but always on next item (on second item).

Comment: Did you check the posted value in CPU? Is it really null, or it throws exception without being null

Comment: It acts quiet strange actually. When I put validation into comment, it normally crates configuration and puts it into DB. But when I uncomment it, it says that also motherboard is null but throws exception on CPU null test.

Comment: I mean when I run this without validation implemented it creates configuration with CPU and everything without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU seems to be treated by the entity framework as a [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).  Without more information this suggests that you'll need to:

1. `using System.Data.Entity` in whatever unit selects the model
2. `.Include(c => c.CPU)` before enumerating the query from the database

If that's truly a [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx), as it appears, it may be [lazily loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) as documented in the Entity Framework materials.

This means that even though the values seem to exist in the database the actual collection --or in your case, reference-- will be null in memory.  So we tell the entity framework to "include" those items when we fetch:

```
var configuration = db.ConfigurationsOrSomething
    .Include(c => c.CPU)
    .Where(c => c.DeletedOrWhatever == false)
    .ToList();

var cpu = configuration.CPU;

if(cpu == null)
    Debug.WriteLine("Something else is the problem. :(");
```

You did say that you've seen the value in the database.  We can't see the code that you've used to select the entity from the database --or anything else, if there is anything else.  We also *can* see that CPU is another type you've defined and referenced.  Your model looks like [EF Code First / Table-per-Type](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545395/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Understanding-Table-Per-Ty) if you need to know more about it along with a tutortial.

Note: I've re-read your comments in a new light.  When you were asked if it was getting into the database you agreed that it was "created normally" without validation.

I'm now considering your entire setup to be a simple validation failure.  If the validation says CPU is null... then CPU is null.

So: where is the code that you are using to *create* the new instance of this `Configuration` entity?  Are you simply not assigning a value to CPU?

Comment: can you explain the second step a bit more please? I would post the whole project if I could...